# resultcode forever 0 and data forever null, not using fragments

Tags: android

Pardon me as I'm rather new to programming, pls do explain in simple terms if possible! any form of help is greatly appreciated, I might not be fully understanding the problem and would like to clear any misconceptions I have about it. I am currently using a 3rd party photo editor SDK, and I have followed their step by step guide in implementing it. However, the result returned to OnActivityResult is always null for the data and 0 for the result code.

I have already included permissions in my manifest code to allow for the reading and writing of external storage

these are my XML permissions

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

1. The method from the parent activity is first called from my recyclerAdapter

```java
 @Override
    public void openPhotoEditor(int p) {
    mcontext = parent.getContext();
    ((CardView) mcontext).openPhotoEditor(p);
    }
```

2. following which, startActivityFromResult is subsequently called from CardView

```java
public void openPhotoEditor(int p){

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.storage/drawable/groupicon");
    try{
        InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){

    }

    Intent dsPhotoEditorIntent = new Intent(this, DsPhotoEditorActivity.class);
    dsPhotoEditorIntent.setData(uri);

    dsPhotoEditorIntent.putExtra(DsPhotoEditorConstants.DS_PHOTO_EDITOR_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY, OUTPUT_PHOTO_DIRECTORY);

    int[] toolsToHide = {};
    dsPhotoEditorIntent.putExtra(DsPhotoEditorConstants.DS_PHOTO_EDITOR_TOOLS_TO_HIDE, toolsToHide);

    startActivityForResult(dsPhotoEditorIntent, DS_PHOTO_EDITOR_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

the 3rd party activity loads fine and I'm able to edit images inside the photo editor

3. when onActivityResult is called, the data returns null and resultCode returns 0

```java
@Override protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int 
resultCode,v Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if( resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    switch (requestCode) {           
       case DS_PHOTO_EDITOR_REQUEST_CODE:
            Uri outputUri = data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap =        
         MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), 
         outputUri);
         listofitems.add(bitmap);
         wallpaper.notifyDataSetChanged();
         }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
         }catch (IOException e) {
         }
```

once again, any form of help or explanations is greatly appreciated!!! happy coding everyone!

Comment: `data returns null and resultcode returns 0` this is done by `the 3rd party activity` which neither we nor you can influence. Probably it has some bugs

Comment: Latest android API's (after 23) require run time permission, make sure you are using that before startActivityForResult.

Comment: @Neck it worked!!! thanks a bunch!!! turns out the problem was that i had to request for run time permission after all! im so relieved